# tar: Remove leading / from member names when using -X (exclude file)

Tags: bash, tar

I am getting the error:

```
Remove leading / from member names
```

when attempting to create a domain archive using -X and a exclude file. If I remove the -X option the job executes as expected.

backup exec

```
/mnt/15326/s3/backup.sh
```

tmp dir

```
/mnt/15326/s3/data
```

exclude file

```
/mnt/15326/s3/data/exclude.txt
```

with contents

```
/mnt/15326/www.domain.com/dir1
/mnt/15326/www.domain.com/dir2
```

dir to backup

```
/mnt/15326/www.domain.com
```

command to run

```
tar cf /mnt/15326/s3/data/backup_domain.com -X /mnt/15326/s3/data/exclude.txt /mnt/15326/www.domain.com
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a warning only. It means that in the tar file the file names wont contain the beginning /. They will be converted to relatives. Use -P if it disturbs you. generaly this default behaviour is a bit safer.

Comment: It's not that it disturbs me, it's not excluding the directory. I assumed the warning had something to do with it.

Comment: The exclude file should contain exclude patterns.Put a * after the dir names.